# Set nonce value on javascript tag

Tags: javascript, security, asp.net-mvc-4

Trying to set a nonce value to a script - on an ASP.NET MVC app (on .NET 4.8).

But the output value is empty - while if I use the exact same method on a hidden input field for setting the value, it works

```
<input id="xptoAAA" type="hidden" value="@Html.ScriptNonce()"/>
<script type="text/javascript" @Html.ScriptNonce() >

</script>
```

Output:

[image]

Shouldn't the "nonce" had also a value set?

Answer (score 1):

Where are you looking for it?

In the **Elements** panel it doesn't show up.
[image]

But in the **Sources** panel it does.
[image]